# What are some resources/advice for GMs looking to hone improvisational skills?

Tags: gm-techniques, roleplaying, improvisation

In an effort to prep for a one-shot that I'm running next month, I'm looking for any guides, videos, podcasts, etc. aimed at helping a GM refine their improvisational skills. I'm giving our DM a little break with a mini-adventure of my own design, and while I'm really excited to cut my teeth on DMing, I'd like to find some resources (ideally GM-oriented) to build up those ad-libbing muscles. My roommates & I have recently been playing [Fiasco](https://bullypulpitgames.com/games/fiasco/) which is fantastic improv practice, but that particular game has no GM. I'd ideally like some practical advice on good rules of thumb for encouraging the "Yes, and" spirit while also knowing how and when to gently course-correct.

I recently read through ["The Lazy Dungeon Master" by Michael E. Shea](https://slyflourish.com/lazydm/), and the main philosophy it emphasizes is that over-preparation can sometimes be detrimental to how much fun everyone's having; when done right, only a basic amount of preparation is necessary to allow room for creative collaborative play. As a fan of improv comedy & lighthearted tones in my own RP, I'm all for this loosely-structured approach. But 99.9% of my RPG experience is on the players' side of the GM's screen, so I'm hoping to get a better idea of how to foster this environment when I'm also the one setting the overall pace of the story.

I also just started [the Master Manual podcast](https://podbay.fm/p/master-manual), which is chock-full of general GM advice - if anyone knows specific episodes of this show (or any others) that have what I'm looking for, please share 'em!

Comment: I think you will have better luck trying a traditional forum, see here for a curated list: https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go